# How do I limit the number of results from a search query with hook_query_alter?

Tags: database

I've followed the Drupal 7 documentation for **hook_query_alter()** in order to limit the number of total search results when searching for nodes or users to an arbitrary number.

However, with the following code (and the example in the documentation) this function has no effect:

```
function mymodule_query_alter(QueryAlterableInterface &$query)
{
    $query->range(0, 3);
}
```

The code is getting executed, because adding a line using the **dpm()** function works and information is outputted, so the hook is getting executed. However, the $query->range(0, 3) method appears to have no effect.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

I am using the **custom_search** module for **Drupal 7**.

I can change the number of results displayed on each page with the following code in **hook_query_alter()**:

```
$results_per_page = 20;

if ($query instanceof PagerDefault
    && ($tables = $query->getTables())
    && isset($tables['i']['table'])
    && $tables['i']['table'] === 'search_index')
{
    $query->limit($results_per_page);
}
```

But what I'd like to do is limit the total number of results before being paginated; if there are 234 results, I'd like to limit the number to, say, 100.

I am guessing that this is not working because I'm using the custom_search module.

Thanks.

Comment: Is the query tagged? https://www.drupal.org/node/310077

Comment: @Cyclone if hook fires, then query was tagged. **But** we don't know if the query OP wants is. We don't know if this code fires for his query. I **strongly suggest** to only use (https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_query_TAG_alter/7

Comment: @Mołot - I'm not so sure that the hook fires, that the reason I'm asking.

Comment: @Cyclone OP wrote he used `dpm` in hook, and it fired. But he didn't write what it shown, so we don't know for *what* it fired... That was my point. By the way, unconditional limiting queries is... Bold move. I wouldn't dare.

Comment: I apologize for any confusion. The hook is executed, but the $query->range method doesn't change anything.